# Send data to remote server using Sockets

Tags: c#, android

I want send data to remote server i know its IP address and Port number. Let say it is xxx.xxx.xx.xx and port number is 123. It works with TCP. I want to send first-last name, email, and host name where host name is the new name which i am going to give my machine. Server should give me response in the form of key value as 123-01234.  Here I do not understand how i would send data to server using socket. I did work with just simple strings. I have one last more question, Have i need to make server program in it.

```
 public  void Connect(String server)
{
Int32 port = 123;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
string FNAME = "reet";
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FNAME);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", FNAME);
data = new Byte[256];
String responseData = String.Empty;
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
stream.Close();
client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why do this with sockets? Why not use HTTP? If you use sockets, you'll need to implement a protocol for delimiting messages, acknowledgement etc. HTTP has done this for you. Don't go reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @spender that seems ... hasty. Either would be perfectly valid in my opinion, and a raw TCP socket is by no means an unusual API.

Comment: I didn't understand your final question "Have i need to make server program in it.", so I didn't attempt to comment on that. If you can clarify, that'd be great

Comment: Thank you spender and  Marc Gravell. I have seen many programs in stackoverflow. There are everywhere two programs are made one for client and one for server. My question is that Do i need to make a  program for server because i am working on remote server or i would need only work with client program. I am new programmer. I made simple programs I don't know much more about socket programming. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MarcGravell Perhaps yes, but the kinds of payload mentioned here really don't merit anything too complex and leave me wondering if the OP has properly considered moving to a higher layer of the stack.

Comment: Thank you Marc Gravell, I have made connection with remote server using TCP/IP it gives response now. But Now, i want to send command to server. it includes my first name, last name as FNAME, LNAME, EMAIL AND HOST-NAME and I am making this program for registration so after that server will return regstration number. when i try to send data it says, 530 command 'fnam' command not accepted in this state. Now i don't understand how to bind all data in one string or what format should i use to send data so that i can send it to remote server. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open a socket, you can either use the `Socket` type, or the `TcpClient` type (assuming it is TCP). The IP address and port are specified in the constructor for either. Then you need to decide whether you're going to use the `Socket` API, vs the `NetworkStream` API, to actually do the communications. If you're using a raw `Socket` (`.Client` on a `TcpClient`), then you use the `Send` and `Receive` methods (and the related async options). If you prefer a `Stream`, then that is `.GetStream()` on `TcpClient`, or `new NetworkStream(socketInstance)` for `Socket`, and `Read` / `Write`. With a `Stream`, you can of course wrap it in a `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` if you want a simple text API, but it isn't clear whether your socket API is text or binary. You mention wanting to receive 123-01234, but that could be encoded many different ways, so ultimately you need to be **very** clear about what the socket API expects, at the byte level.